# Screen only Google sign in with Actions on Google Java Library?

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm starting to use the AoG java library and from the examples it looks like the SignIn helper only works with devices with screens.

From [this sample repo](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-helper-intents-java):

`signin_placeholder_error=Sign in is only available on devices with a screen`

The [javadoc](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-java/) also says this about Sign In:

```
public SignIn()
Hands the user off to a web sign in flow. App sign in and OAuth credentials are set in the Actions console.
```

I know this is a capability that the nodeJS library has. Is this a limitation of the java library, or is this a feature that exists or is coming soon?

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake in the sample. If using Google Sign-In, this will work for devices without a screen as well.

EDIT: The sample has now been updated with a fix to clarify that Google Sign-In works even on phones without a screen.